# jquery get value of a group of text box

Tags: coffeescript

i have a group of textboxes which has same css class:

```
                input.push-at.input-small(type='text')
                input.push-at.input-small(type='text')
                input.push-at.input-small(type='text')
                input.push-at.input-small(type='text')
                input.push-at.input-small(type='text')
```

now i need to iterate through these textboxes and read the values, i tried the following but it didn't work:

```
hours = []
for h in $(@el).find('.push-at')
  alert(h.val())   <-- complaint 'undefined is not a function'
  hours.push h.val()
```

when i debug in the browser it showed h is a input element and has value, then why it complaint? thanks

Comment: h needs to be a jquery function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`h` needs to be a jquery object. try:

```
hours = []
for h in $(@el).find('.push-at')
  alert($(h).val())   <-- complaint 'undefined is not a function'
  hours.push $(h).val()
```

ie. `$(h).val()` so that you can pull the jquery function `val()` of of `h`.